# JComponent permanently repainting

Tags: java, swing, out-of-memory, repaint, jcomponent

So I have a JFrame with some Buttons and a JComponent to draw in. I load some Images and paint the 1st in the JComponent. Now my problem is that my JComponent, as soon as I paint the 1st time, is permanently repainting and after a few seconds I get an OutOfMemoryError... 
I think the `g.drawImage(...)` is the problem because if i comment it out there is no infinite loop anymore:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    System.out.println("Test");
    if(!images.isEmpty()){
        Image img = activeImage.img.getScaledInstance(middleImage.getWidth(), middleImage.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        if(mode != 0){
            if(mis != null){
                img = createImage(mis).getScaledInstance(middleImage.getWidth(), middleImage.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);                      
            }
        }
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do the people who intend to help you a favour and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 1) You need to run `repaint` and `revalidate' on event dispatch thread (EDT) via `invokeLater`. 2) Your threads, in particular the `ContinousDraw` go into loop and never sleep which can impact EDT ability to properly repaint. 3)  `createImage(mis)` in the loop can cause out of memory if it is run way too many times.

Comment: Don't update the state of any component from within any paint method

Comment: Already changed that.

Comment: But still no [mcve] -- too bad.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels now you got what ya want :)

Comment: Nope -- re-read the [mcve] link please. It needs to be a very small but complete stand-alone program that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually painting anything, and setBounds does call invalidate (that calls repaint)

So this block:

```
    newImage.setBounds(560, 640 + this.getHeight()-720, 720 + this.getWidth()-1280, 40);
    scrollRoom.setBounds(0, 0, 437, this.getHeight());
    middleImage.setBounds(560, 0, this.getWidth()-560, this.getHeight()-80);
    autoFade.setBounds(436, 0, 124, 100);
    createHistogram.setBounds(436, 100, 124, 100);
    imageMorphology.setBounds(436, 200, 124, 100);
    editImage.setBounds(436, 300, 124, 100);
    endActiveMode.setBounds(436, this.getHeight() - (720-573), 124, 100);
```

Must be moved to the constructor before setVisible(true)

And you dont need to override paint(Graphics)

The second problem is your threads, by calling run you execute it on main thread, call instead:

```
super.start();
```

Comment: No, you need to remove the paint @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: I put that in paint so it repaints the components in the JFrame when it's resized. But while I write this I think about putting it in a resize listener.

Comment: But this didn't change the permanent repaint for the JComponent :/

Comment: About the resize, you better be using layout managers instead of setBounds

Comment: @ultimate2106 Get rid of the `paint` method; make use of appropriate layouts managers; this, and a bunch of other issues, will all go away